# Exclude a folder from roaming profiles

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-domain, roaming-profiles

How can I exclude a folder from roaming profiles on a Windows 7 client machine?

Microsoft has two articles on how to exclude it using group policy on the domain controller (For [Windows 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=315415) and [Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=814592)), and you used to be able to edit `NTUser.ini` to exclude them but all changes are ignored and wiped out as soon as I log out.

How can I, as a user (I have local and domain admin access but not the procedural authority) stop these folders from being synched back to the profiles share?

Some of the folders I want to exclude can be moved to another location, but not all, and for the ones that can, I only want to exclude a particular sub directory.

Thanks.

Comment: I found your problem. Roaming profiles can only be used as mandatory profiles. Mandatory profiles can't be modified by the user. I don't know of a workaround other than using the DC.

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean? It's not a mandatory profile as everything else is synched back to the server (and I know it's a full roaming profile)

Comment: Mandatory profiles are defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ... in windows, all roaming profiles are mandatory profiles the modified settings are only good for that session, once you log off the setting revert back to the admin settings. How are the folders/files "synched back to the profile shares"?

Comment: I'm sorry but you're wrong, as the linked article says, a mandatory profile is a special type of full roaming profile. By default they are not mandatory. My profile is NOT a mandatory profile, it is a full roaming profile. The synchronisation is done as part of the normal windows mechanism as described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776892(v=vs.85).aspx). "Changes made to a roaming user profile are synchronized with the server copy of the profile when the user logs off."

Comment: sorry-my mistake. roaming profiles aren't necessarily mandatory profiles, but they can be. If your settings aren't being saved, it may mean that your roaming profile is a mandatory profile, your network admin would know for sure. As far as your question, the only way I know of going about what you want to do would be to move the subfolder to another location, like your home directory...or by using Group Policy Objects in Active Directory to specify the specific folders to exclude.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I know my profile is not mandatory. All other settings are synced both ways on login and logout, EXCEPT the `NTUser.ini` which, I assume is overridden by the GPO.

Comment: I don't think `NTUser.ini` is used anymore. I'm pretty sure that the profile information is stored in NTUser.dat (these move profile settings into the registry) or NTUser.man (for mandatory profiles). Admins can change a profile to mandatory by changing the .dat to .man. This makes the profile read-only. Many organizations use these profiles for non-admin users in case they make changes to the system configuration that they don't know how to fix.

Comment: Sadly, the `ExclusionList` value doesn't seem to be mapped into the registry.